# npm install react-router-dom install error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have tried several times to install react-router-dom in my react project but it keeps on giving me the following error:

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4 npm ERR! Found:
> react@18.2.0 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   peer
> react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@testing-library/react npm ERR!
> @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project npm ERR!   peer
> react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/react-dom npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from
> @testing-library/react@13.4.0    npm ERR!
> node_modules/@testing-library/react npm ERR!
> @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project       npm ERR!
> peer react-dom@">=16.6.0" from react-transition-group@4.4.5    npm
> ERR!     node_modules/react-transition-group npm ERR!
> react-transition-group@"^4.4.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@material-ui/core npm ERR!         peer
> @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@material-ui/icons npm ERR!         1 more (the root
> project) npm ERR!     2 more (the root project, react-router-dom) npm
> ERR!   5 more (react-router, react-scripts, react-transition-group,
> ...) npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
> react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@material-ui/core npm ERR!   peer
> @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3   npm ERR!
> node_modules/@material-ui/icons npm ERR!
> @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project npm ERR!
> @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2 npm ERR! node_modules/react
> npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from
> @material-ui/core@4.12.4    npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
> npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from
> @material-ui/icons@4.11.3npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
> npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project npm
> ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
> command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm
> ERR! See C:\Users\NKEM AWA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt
> for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\User
> Name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-31T18_23_30_712Z-debug-0.log

Please if you know how to resolve this help. I am using the react@18.2.0

`npm install react-router-dom` as per the Router manual and it kept on giving me an error. I wanted to use route in the project but I am unable to do so because of this installation error.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because your materialui version is peer dependency with react 16.8.0 || ^17.0.0

You can fix this error by install lower react version

Comment: Thanks, I actually forced the installation and it worked with the current version of react.